# Mongodb findOneAndUpdate() compare sums of date and timestamps

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nodes, findoneandupdate

I'm working on a MongoDB (+mongoose) based scheduler where tasks have the following type

```
TaskSchema {
  running: Boolean
  executedAt: Date,
  next: Number (millisecond)
}
```

I wish to fetch Tasks which should be executed meaning the sum of `executedAt + next < now`
Since the scheduler should lock the Task, the `running` flag should be flipped to true in the same operation, hence I'm using `findOneAndUpdate()`
I'm stuck at dealing with the sum of executedAt and next. How would one compare the sum of these to `new Date/Date.now()` ?

When doing an aggregation one could use `$dateAdd` from what I understand so in a find query could be something. like the following:

```
    Task.find({
      $and: [
        { running: { $ne: null } },
        { running: false },
        { next: { $ne: null } },
        { executedAt: { $ne: null } },
        {
          $expr: {
            $lt: [
              {
                $dateAdd: {
                  startDate: '$executedAt',
                  unit: 'millisecond',
                  amount: '$next',
                },
              },
              new Date().toUTCString(),
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    })
```

However this does not work.

Comment: Don't compare a `Date` with a string. Simply use `new Date()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my initial attempt works and the above query is nearly correct. Since I didn't set the `$addDate` timezone explicitly I tried making the `new Date()` a UTC string. Considering [@Wernfrieds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit) comment this complies to my requirements:

```
Task.find({
  $and: [
    { running: { $ne: null } },
    { running: false },
    { next: { $ne: null } },
    { executedAt: { $ne: null } },
    {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          {
            $dateAdd: {
              startDate: '$executedAt',
              unit: 'millisecond',
              amount: '$next',
            },
          },
          new Date(),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
})
```